# Python function printng out sum for all evens (1-10) but not the numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I made a python function where it suppose to print out even numbers from 1-100 and add the sum. I managed to print out the sum but the numbers don't print out.

```
def main():
    BuildList()

def BuildList():
    lstEvens = []
    for i in range(0,101):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            lstEvens.append(i)
    SumList(lstEvens)

def SumList(lstEvens):
    totalofEvens = sum(lstEvens)
    ShowResults(totalofEvens)

def ShowResults(totalofEvens):
    print("The sum of all Even numbers combined is" ,totalofEvens)
    print(lstEvens)

main()
```

Comment: You may want to add another `print` somewhere.

Comment: `lstEvens` is not in the scope of `ShowResults`.  Either move your print to `SumList`, or pass `lstEvents` to `ShowResults`.

Comment: I added the lstEvens to ShowResults and it gave me this error message when running.                                                                                  TypeError: ShowResults() missing 1 required positional argument: 'totalofEvens'                                                                                             Also I added the print statement to the sumlist and that works but I need to organize it by having the sum on the bottom and the list of evens on top. Sorry for asking so much.

Answer (score 0):

`lstEvens` is not defined in the function `ShowResults`.